# CSS: Strange Edge for Color Blocks

Tags: html, css, background

Given a block with background color, if it's put in another color block, a strange edge is shown.

See the below image. This blue block is put in a red body. There seems to be a black border in the top and left side, while white border in the bottom and right side.
[image]

Here's the code example, [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ytwf1uv3/):

```
<body style="background: red;width:100vw;height:100vh;">
  <div style="background:#4CAF50; width: 150px; height: 50px;color: white;margin: 150px auto;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: it's an optical illusion

Answer (score 1):

it's an optical illusion because of color's